# jsx must wrap with an enclosing tag error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my map below? Everything is wrapped properly but I still getting error of `jsx must wrap with an enclosing tag`

```
<div className="col-md-12">
    {items.map(obj => {
        <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
        <p className="edited">Last updated on {obj.updated_at}</p>
        <div className="actions_wrap">
            <Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>
            <a>Delete</a>
        </div>
    })}
</div>
```

This line has error if I wrap the stuff with a `div`:

`<Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>`

Comment: Your map isn't returning a component. Either change the `=> { ... }` to `=> ( ... )` or add a return. You may also need to wrap the contents in a single element

Answer (score 1):

JSX has a current limitation whereby there can only be 1 top level node returned from a statement.

From [JSX in depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children)

> A React component can't return multiple React elements, but a single JSX expression can have multiple children, so if you want a component to render multiple things you can wrap it in a div like this

If your example, you have 3 nodes as siblings to one another: h2, p and div.

You can solve this issue by wrapping them all in 1 top level container:

```
<div className="col-md-12">
    {items.map(obj => {
        <div>
            <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
            <p className="edited">Last updated on {obj.updated_at}</p>
            <div className="actions_wrap">
                <Link to=`/item/edit/${obj._id}`>Edit</Link>
                <a>Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: this line is not working `<Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>`

Comment: You can change the line to: `<Link to=\`/item/edit/${obj._id}\`>Edit</Link>` - Notice the use of backticks for string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `.map` returns multiple elements. Perhaps you should wrap that in a `div`?

```
<div className="col-md-12">
    {items.map(obj => {
        <div>
            <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
            <p className="edited">Last updated on {obj.updated_at}</p>
            <div className="actions_wrap">
                <Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>
                <a>Delete</a>
            </div>
        <div>
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: should probably also replace those curly braces with parens

Comment: @Daniel, I got error on this line `<Link to="/item/edit/"{obj._id}>Edit</Link>`

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you're map is returning. Each DOM element in jsx is essentially an object so your map is trying to return several things which isn't allowed in javascript. The solution to this in jsx is to wrap a collection of dom elements with another dom element so that the content remains, but you're fulfilling javascript's requirement that a function only returns one thing.